# Regex for conditionally extracting a named group

Tags: python, regex

I have a requirement to write python flavoured regex to extract a field conditionally. The following are the two types of test strings that I need to extract from:

```
 http://domain/string1/path/field_to_extract/path/filename
 http://domain/string2/path/90020_10029/path/filename
```

Below is my requirement:

1. For string2 we should only pick the number at the fourth location, between slash (/) and (_).
2. For others we should pick the whole text between the slashes (/) at the fourth location.

I have written the following regex:

```
(?i)^(?:[^ ]*(?: {1,2})){6}(?:[a-z]+://)(?:[^ /:]+[^ /]/:]+[^ /]+/[^ /]+/)?(?:[^ /]+/){2}(?P<field_name>(?<=/string2/)(?:[^/]+/)([^_]+)|((?<!/string2/)(?:[^/]+/)([^/]+)))
```

Though the conditional extracting seems to be working fine, this regex also matches the string before the field that is extracted. For example, when used on the first test string, this regex matches `path/field_to_extract` and on the second it matches `path/90020`.

Though I have added ignore to the group before the required field, it does not seem to be working.

Please help me in getting the regex right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with pattern `'//[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/(\d+(?=_)|[^/]+)'`

Comment: You can reduce `[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/` to `(?:[^/]+/){3}`

Answer (score 2):

How about using a `split()` instead of a complegex :-

```
s          = 'thelink'.split('/')
if len(s) > 4:
   string1or2 = s[3]
   field      = s[5]

   if string1or2 == 'string2':
       print field.split('_')[0]
else:
   raise ValueError("Incorrect URL")
```

Comment: You could use split for the second case as well

Comment: I've edit your script to avoid some exception (id the thelink doesn't contains slashes for example)

Comment: Thanks for the answer edit @MaximeLorant . Never seen anyone taking all the trouble before :)

Answer (score 0):

A pure `regex` solution:

```
import re

urls = [
    r'''http://domain/string1/path/field_to_extract/path/filename''',
    r'''http://domain/string2/path/90020_10029/path/filename'''
]

for url in urls:
    print(re.search(r'(?<![:/])/(?:(string2)|[^/]*)/[^/]*/((?(1)[^_]*|[^/]*))', url).group(2))
```

**Explanation:**

`(?<![:/])/` :: Search for a slash that doesn't follow another slash or a colon.

`(?:(string2)|[^/]*)/` :: Match the literal "string2" or any other thing. If it's the first one, save it as group-1 to do a conditional *yes-no-pattern* later.

`[^/]*/` :: Match second part of the path. No interesting.

`((?(1)[^_]*|[^/]*))` :: If exists group-1, match until first `_` (`[^_]*`). Otherwise match until next slash (`[^/]*`).

It yields:

```
field_to_extract
90020
```